# Energy storage optimization pyomo piecewise linear expression for constraint

Tags: python, pyomo, piecewise

I am building an energy storage optimisation model with pyomo and I am trying to formulate a piecewise linear expression within it. I am new to python and pyomo so I would really appreciate some help.

I want to include a constraint to the model which only applies for positive values of my decision variable.

So far, that constraint is:

```
def constraint_storage_level(model,t):
    return model.Q[t] == (model.Q[t-1]*model.loss) + model.q_net[t]*model.loss_dyn[t]*model.COP_factor[t]
```

The idea is that `model.loss_dyn[t]`only applies for positive `model.q_net[t]`
I think I need to use a piecewise linear expression here as my model linear.
I already found that documentation: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Expressions.html.

Does someone has an idea how to proceed?

Here is what I tried to include so far:

```
model.T = RangeSet(0, 35039)
model.q_net = Var(model.T, domain=Reals, bounds=(-100,100))
domain = [-100.,0.,0.,100]
f = [1., 1., 0.95, 0.95]

model.loss_dyn = Piecewise(model.T, model.q_net,
                     pw_pts=domain,
                     pw_constr_type='EQ',
                     f_rule=f,
                     pw_repn='INC',
                     unbounded_domain_var=True)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to add what happens if `model.q_net[t]` is equal to 0? Does the constraint not apply anymore or does it take another form?

Comment: If `model.q_net[t]`is equal to 0, `model.loss_dyn[t]` does not apply anymore, but the the constraint `constraint_storage_level(model.t) does apply within the model. I hope this helps you understanding the problem. I will also edit my post and add what I already tried.

Comment: Do you mean that if `model.q_net[t]` is equal to 0, `model.loss_dyn[t]` is equal to 0 too? Or does it become equal to 1, thus, not having an impact? Have a look at these examples here: https://projects.coin-or.org/Coopr/browser/coopr.pyomo/trunk/examples/pyomo/piecewise?rev=5221&order=name

Comment: `model.loss_dyn[t]` becomes 1 in that case. 
In fact, the `constraint_storage_level(model.t)` is the constraint for the energy storage level. What I want to include are losses (`model.loss_dyn[t]`), which only apply if energy is charged to the storage (which is the case if `model.q_net[t]` is positive). If `model.q_net[t]` is 0 or negatve, then no losses occur. That is what I want to include to the model.

Comment: Well, if `model.q_net[t]` is zero (i.e. no charging or discharging happening), then the whole product in which it is involved is zero and it does not matter anymore what the value of `model.loss_dyn[t]` is, right? In this case, the constraint becomes `model.Q[t] == (model.Q[t-1]*model.loss)`.

Comment: Yes, that is right!

Comment: So, did this then answer your question or you still need to solve this?

Comment: I think I found the correct code. But now I have an error that the `solver is unable to handle quadtratic expressions` . I am using glpk as solver. I tried the ipopt solver, but then I get the error that the solver does not know the `pw_constr_type` . So, I did not solved it yet.
I will try to separate `model.q_net` into two variables (`model.q_charge` and `model.q_discharge`), but I am not sure whether I can then stay with the linear optimization.

Comment: Which term in your constraint is quadratic now? At any case, though, you can try the Gurobi solver, as it can handle quadratic expressions. As for the split of the `q_net[t]` term into two terms, I think that this is the most common practice in energy storage modelling and I do not see why the formulation would be nonlinear.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!
I now splitted `q_net[t]` into two terms. The problem I have now is that in some periods charge and discharge happens simultaneously which is not possible in my model. So I added thw following constraint to avoid that:
`def constraint_simultaneous_ch_dis(model,t):
    return model.q_charge[t]*model.q_discharge[t] == 0 `
such that either `q_charge`or `q_discharge`becomes zero.
Of course, I have a quadratic expression again.Do you have an idea how I could implement a similar constraint, but without a quadratic expression in order to stay with the glpk solver?

Comment: Hi, the standard approach in the literature to do that is to define two binary variables (i.e. variables that are either 0 or 1) - one that becomes equal to 1 when charging happens, and one with similar functionality for discharging. Let's call them `y_charge[t]` and `y_discharge[t]`. Now to enforce them to become 1 when charging/discharging happens you need BigM constraints: `q_charge[t] <= M * y_charge[t]`, where M is a sufficiently large number (same for discharging). Then to prevent simultaneous charging and discharging, you add this constraint: `y_charge[t] + y_discharge[t] <= 1`.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I totally forgot to tell you that it worked with that approach! :) I think it is a quite nice solution! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Good luck with your project!